# How to target first img in every wordpress post with CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to target first image in every post. The example post where I am trying to perform this is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170905200957/http://hilarioust.com:80/2016/04/13/woman-uses-her-hijab-to-turn-herself-into-disney-princesses/).
So I tried to use `first-of-type` like this

```
.single-post .entry-content img.aligncenter:first-of-type {

width: 80% !important;
float: left;


}
```

And also tried to replace `first-of-type` with `first-child` and I get the same result and that is every image is selected instead of first one. I think that this should only select the first image with occurrence of `.aligncenter` class.

Comment: Try this one on Stack Overflow , you will get much more detailed answers

Comment: I would but I have been blocked from asking question there, reason is pretty unknown to me, I belive it is due to some "off-topic" questions. Anyway thank you really on your time and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly i would say this is off-topic here as it purely relates to css/js, but let me try to give some pointers.

Here you markup is :

```
<article>
    <header></header>
    <div>
    ....
    <p><img class="align-center" src="path/to/img1"></p>
    ....
    <p><img class="align-center" src="path/to/img2"></p>
    ....
    </div>
</article>
```

**first-of-type** means selecting the first child of the selector parent.

In the above markup , the targeted selector is **image with class align-center** and the selector parent is **p**. So selecting the first child of the selector parent matches both images. That's why both images are being styled.

**first-child** means select an element if it is an image with class align-center **and** and is the first child of a parent selector. So it matches both images.

I would recommend using JavaScript selectors here.

```
document.querySelector(".single-post .entry-content img.aligncenter")
```

returns first element in the result.

If you are using jQuery use `:first` filter.

**References:**

[first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)

[first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505686/first-child-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this topic to me. I really appriciate :).